# While performing the delete operation in the following code, I am not able to get the correct values returned in the following code.

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, queue, dynamic-memory-allocation

Unable to print the correct values of deleted elements from the queue. DeQueue() is used for deleting the elements. I have used dynamic circular array implementation technique for the QUEUE, i.e., doubling of the memory when the QUEUE is full. The first element returned in the deletion process is correct but after that, if deletion is performed again, then random values are returned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct DynArrayQueue{
    int front, rear;
    int capacity;
    int* array;
};

void ResizeQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q);

struct DynArrayQueue* CreateDynQueue(){

    struct DynArrayQueue* Q = (struct DynArrayQueue* )malloc(sizeof(struct DynArrayQueue));

    if(!Q)
    {
        cout << "Memory Error in allocation!\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    Q->capacity = 1;
    Q->front = Q->rear = -1;
    Q->array = (int* )malloc(Q->capacity * sizeof(int));

    if(!Q->array)
     {
         cout << "Memory error in creating queue!\n";
         return NULL;
     }

    return Q;
}

int IsEmptyQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){
    if(Q->front == -1){
        cout << "Queue is empty!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Queue not empty\n";
        return 0;
    }
}

int IsFullQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){
    if((((Q->rear)+1)%Q->capacity) == Q->front)
    {
        cout << "Queue is full!\n";
        return 1;
    }else{
        cout << "Queue not full!\n";
        return 0;
    }
}

void QueueSize(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){
    int s;
    s = (Q->capacity - Q->front + Q->rear + 1) % Q->capacity;
    cout << "Size of the queue is " << s;
    cout << "\n\n";
}

void EnQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){
    int data;
    cout << "Enter the data to be inserted:\n";
    cin >> data;
    if(IsFullQueue(Q))
      {
          ResizeQueue(Q);
      }
    Q->rear = (Q->rear + 1)%Q->capacity;
    Q->array[Q->rear] = data;
    if(Q->front == -1)
    {
        Q->front = Q->rear;
    }
}

void ResizeQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){
    int size = Q->capacity;
    Q->capacity = Q->capacity * 2;
    Q->array = (int* )realloc(Q->array, Q->capacity);
    if(!Q->array)
          cout << "Memory error!\n";
    if(Q->front > Q->rear)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Q->front; i++)
        {
            Q->array[i+size] = Q->array[i];
        }
        Q->rear = Q->rear + size;
    }
}

void DeQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){    **this function does not work properly**
    int data = 0;
    if(IsEmptyQueue(Q))
    {
        cout << "Queue Underflow!\n";
        cout << "No element to delete!\n";
    }
    else{
        data = Q->array[Q->front];
        if(Q->front == Q->rear)
        {
            Q->front = Q->rear = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            Q->front = ((Q->front) + 1) % Q->capacity;
        }
    }
    cout << "Element deleted is " << data;
    cout << "\n";
}

void DeleteQueue(struct DynArrayQueue* Q){
    if(Q){
        if(Q->array)
        {
            free(Q->array);
        }
        free(Q);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    struct DynArrayQueue* Q1;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "1. Press to create a Queue:\n";
        cout << "2. Enter an element in the queue:\n";
        cout << "3. Delete an element from the queue:\n";
        cout << "4. Press to know the Queue size:\n";
        cout << "5. Press to know if Queue is full:\n";
        cout << "6. Press to know if Queue is empty:\n";
        cout << "7. Press enter to exit:\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice:\n";
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            Q1 = CreateDynQueue();
            break;
        case 2:
            EnQueue(Q1);
            break;
        case 3:
            DeQueue(Q1);
            break;
        case 4:
            QueueSize(Q1);
            break;
        case 5:
            IsFullQueue(Q1);
            break;
        case 6:
            IsEmptyQueue(Q1);
            break;
        case 7:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong choice entered!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    DeleteQueue(Q1);
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add some input, expected out, and the observed output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't in `DeleteQueue`, it is in `ResizeQueue`.  When you call `realloc`, you're passing in the new number of elements but not factoring in the size of the elements (like you are when you initially allocate space).  It should be

```
Q->array = (int* )realloc(Q->array, Q->capacity * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `ResizeQueue()`.

The statement

```
Q->array = (int* )realloc(Q->array, Q->capacity);
```

does not allocate the right size.   Subsequent operations (until the next `DeleteQueue()`) then happily assume the array is longer than it is, and write past the end.

Also, if `realloc()` fails it returns `NULL` and does not release the old memory.   The result of this assignment is then a memory leak (since the old value of `Q->array` is lost to your program).

What you actually need to do (at minimum) is

```
int *temp = (int* )realloc(Q->array, Q->capacity * sizeof(int));
if (!temp)
    cout << "Memory error!\n";
else
    Q->array = temp;
```

Even that is not sufficient, since subsequent code uses `Q->array` and assumes the resizing succeeded.   If a failure has occurred, the result is undefined behaviour.    I'll leave addressing that concern properly as a learning exercise.

Also, in C++, consider using standard containers (like `std::vector<int>`) which can resize themselves in a controlled manner - so you can avoid silliness like allocating the wrong amounts of memory.